# Orthogonal Vector Space with Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any way to compute the norm of a vector **v**, only knowing the coordinates of **v** with respect to a known basis B, knowing that B is a <strike>orthonormal</strike> orthogonal basis with inner product.

Comment: if $v=a_1e_1+...+a_ne_n$ then $||v||^2=\langle v,v\rangle=a_1^2+...+a_n^2$ (if $\{e_i\}_i$ is any orthonormal set, then $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$).

Comment: I noticed you just changed the question to orthogonal basis.  This changes the answer.  Now you have to take into account the norms of the basis vectors.  The same method of calculation works though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\textbf{f}_1,\ldots,\textbf{f}_n$ be the orthonormal basis of $V$ and $\textbf{v} = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j\textbf{f}_j$

\begin{align*}\left\langle \textbf{v}, \textbf{v} \right\rangle &= \left\langle \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j\textbf{f}_j , \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\textbf{f}_i\right\rangle\\
&=\sum_{j,i=1}^n\alpha_i \alpha_j \left\langle \textbf{f}_j , \textbf{f}_i \right\rangle\\
&=\sum_{j,i=1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j \delta_{i,j} = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2 \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand what you did in the last step. How did you eliminate  (delta)?

Comment: When $i\neq j$, $\delta_{i,j} = 0$, and when $i=j$, $\delta_{i,j} = 1$, so the only terms we pick up in the sum are $\alpha_i \alpha_i \delta_{i,i} = \alpha_i^2$

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, sorry, I just realize I made a big mistake. Actually, I was refering to an orthogonal basis (not orthonormal). Anyway, this also helps me. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this almost gives you what you want even if your basis is only orthogonal, just keep your factor of $\langle \textbf{f}_i , \textbf{f}_i \rangle$ instead of $\delta_{i,i}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using bilinearity of inner product and the fact that you have an orthonormal basis the norm is just the square root of the sum of the squares of it's coordinates.